# Swift and Sprite Kit - unarchiving a particle emitter (sks) file

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, particles

I am getting an error for this block of code:

```
_bloodEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blood", ofType:"sks"));
```

The error I get is: "Could not find an overload for 'pathForResource' that excepts the supplied arguments"

The documentation reads:

```
func pathForResource(_ name: String?,
          ofType extension: String?) -> String?
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unwrapping the filePath:

```
_bloodEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blood", ofType: "sks")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file path needs to be explicitly unwrapped:

```
_bloodEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blood", ofType:"sks"));
```

I find the best way to deal with compile time errors in Xcode using Swift is to do each part in stages (in this case, declaring the path as it's own String object). When I try to combine things together I typically receive errors like this and end up on a wild goose chase thanks to the compiler giving an extremely unhelpful error message.